# How can I only deploy portions of a big application using `Git`?

Tags: git, deployment, version-control, github

lets say my application is divided into 4 pieces and I want to deploy it to 3 servers, each server will contain 2 pieces, 1 is shared between all the servers and 1 is specific for that server. if I clone the git repo on 1 server all the pieces will be loaded there.

Should I create a git repo for each piece in my code? I guess that will be painful to work with or to sync all the repos specially if i need to create extra pieces in the future.

**Right now**

```
Server1       Server2       Server3
Piece1        Piece1        Piece1
Piece2        Piece2        Piece2
Piece3        Piece3        Piece3
Piece4        Piece4        Piece4
```

**What I'm trying to achieve**

```
Server1       Server2       Server3
Piece1        Piece1        Piece1
Piece2        Piece3        Piece4
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to create a repository for each piece and then use git submodules or subtrees to keep track of the dependencies. The piece which specific for the server includes the shared repository.

Anyway, this way the repository for the specific piece is then fixed to the corresponding server. If you want to share that repository with other servers it won't work.

We use this for our dependency management in our applications. Your "servers" are our "application" where each app has its own repository and we add the dependencies by including additional submodules to that repo.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad idea to structure your code repository, solely based on how it gets deployed.

If each component is truly standalone and can have it's own release cycle, then by all means put them into separate repositories. However a more likely scenario is that you have one large multi-tier application, in which case you are better off creating deployment packages for each of your components.

You have not mentioned what technology you are using, so, if you are using Linux then create RPM packages and push these to an yum repository. Each component then becomes simple to install using the standard "yum install" command.